# Disable HDD through BIOS in ASUS motherboard H81M-PLUS

Tags: hard-drive, bios

Now my desktop has two HDDs, one of them is almost dead. PC cannot even normally boot up because it tries to check both disks. Of course, bad disk can be turned off physically, but is there way to disable it via BIOS? In earlier computers BIOS provides possibility to describe parameters for each master/slave HDD or use autodetect option as well as completely disable that device. Now I see only info what devices are plugged into sots, but cannot disable one of them.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: What are your computer model. BIOS version, and add a screenshot of that screen in the BIOS.

Comment: I read your user manual and it does Not look like you can disable selectively....https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/H81MPLUS/HelpDesk_Manual/

Comment: You might try the Asus chat support in the link i posted.

Comment: Thanks everyone who tried to help. I've asked Asus support, and they confirmed that in modern BIOSes there isn't possibility to disable device in the given slot.